# How can i remove textarea of CKEditor and only use its toolbar?

Tags: jquery, html, ckeditor

I want to implement CKEditor for my web application. I don't need it on every textarea, I want only one CKEditor toolbar on my navigation panel. so for that I need to remove default textarea from CKEditor, all I am saying is how can i only use toolbar of CKEditor?

See in image I have 2 textarea controls and both are having same toolbar, neither its not looks good nor its good way to implementation. 
So i want a single toolbar on top of the page for my both textarea controls.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<body>
<form method="post">
    <p>
        My Editor:<br />
        <textarea id="editor1" name="editor1"></textarea>
        <textarea id="editor1" name="editor2"></textarea>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', { height: 100 });
        CKEDITOR.replace('editor2', { height: 200 });
        </script>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" />
    </p>
</form>
</body>
```

In image i have shown circled area which I want.

[image]

[image]

Comment: what buttons of the toolbar would be useful if there is no textarea?

Comment: none of this makes any sense. What higher level problem are you trying to solve? what does a circle around  toolbar have to do with removing a textarea?

Comment: In my application i have multiple textarea controls and its not a good idea to use ckEditor in each textarea. so i want ro remove default text area and I will place its toolbar navigation panel using it I will facilate users to use tools of ckeditor.

Comment: wait a second i will show you actual thing which bother me. @charlietfl

Comment: i have edited my question with more information.@charlietfl , @sam Battat

Comment: can use inline editor that only shows on demand. Would be more intuitive to user

Comment: So you want one toolbar for multiple textareas?

Answer (score 2):

Most probably you are looking for the shared space plugin, see the example here: http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/sharedspace.html

> The optional Shared Space plugin makes it possible to share the same editor toolbar and bottom bar among several CKEditor instances.